# Open another app with url scheme containing 3 items swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to open another app installed on my iPhone through the app url scheme, I got the url scheme by exporting the app's ipa
[image]

```
@IBAction func openApp(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if let url = URL(string: "avaya://") {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
        }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: What is the question, what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: What happens when you enter the url in Safari ?

Comment: I have the Avaya Workplace app installed on my iPhone and I want to access it through the app I created by clicking on the button

Comment: Did you tried your code and have not opened Avaya App ?

Comment: Yes I tried many times and couldn't but I tried the same code with another app which has one element url scheme and it worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using wrong property.

The "URL Types" ([CFBundleURLTypes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102207)) is the property that controls which schemes will open *your* application.

To allow opening *another* app, use [LSApplicationQueriesSchemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW14):

[image]

Essentially, your definition is saying that `avaya://` links should open *your* app but you are not allowed to use them inside the app.

Comment: Exactly I want to open the Avaya app and not inside my app

Comment: @Ab.sh Did you understand the answer?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand your answer
Can you answer by writing the code?

Comment: There is no code (aside from the code you have already shown). For `canOpenURL` to work you need to set the url scheme in the queries schemes key, not the bundle url types. However, how to format the url so that the other app opens 3 items (whatever they are) is not something you can determine from the other app's info.plist. You need documentation that describes how they use urls.

Comment: @Ab.sh Added an image. Remove "URL Types"